# freeCodeCamp.org - doing javascript tutorial and contract won't deploy on VS

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, ethers.js

I am trying to deploy a SimpleStorage.sol contract using a deploy function on VS.

Error message is:

```
Error: invalid bytecode (argument="bytecode", value="[{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"string\",\"name\":\"_name\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"_favoriteNumber\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"addPerson\",\"outputs\":[],\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"string\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"string\"}],\"name\":\"nameToFavoriteNumber\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"people\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"favoriteNumber\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"internalType\":\"string\",\"name\":\"name\",\"type\":\"string\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"retrieve\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"_favoriteNumber\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"store\",\"outputs\":[],\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"}]", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.7.0)
    at Logger.makeError (/home/ben_hudson/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:238:21)
    at Logger.throwError (/home/ben_hudson/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:247:20)
    at Logger.throwArgumentError (/home/ben_hudson/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:250:21)
    at new ContractFactory (/home/ben_hudson/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index.js:1082:20)
    at main (/home/ben_hudson/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage/deploy.js:20:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ben_hudson/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage/deploy.js:25:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1226:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1280:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1089:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:930:12) {
  reason: 'invalid bytecode',
  code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
  argument: 'bytecode',
  value: '[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"_name","type":"string"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_favoriteNumber","type":"uint256"}],"name":"addPerson","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"name":"nameToFavoriteNumber","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"people","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"favoriteNumber","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"string","name":"name","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"retrieve","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_favoriteNumber","type":"uint256"}],"name":"store","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]'
```

Deploy.js:

```
const ethers = require("ethers"); // const means can't change ethers. require just imports it
const fs = require("fs-extra");

async function main() {
  // compile them in our code
  // compile them separately
  // http://127.0.0.1:7545
  const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
    "http://127.0.0.1:7545"
  );
  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(
    process.env.PRIV_KEY,
    provider
  );
  const abi = fs.readFileSync("./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi", "utf8");
  const binary = fs.readFileSync(
    "./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi",
    "utf8"
  );
  const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, binary, wallet); // used to deploy contract
  console.log("Deploying, pleast wait...");
  const contract = await ContractFactory.deploy(); // STEP here! Wait for contract to deploy --> "await"
  console.log(contract);
}
main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

SimpleStorage.sol

```
// I'm a comment!
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.8.7;

// pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
// pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;

contract SimpleStorage {
    uint256 favoriteNumber;

    struct People {
        uint256 favoriteNumber;
        string name;
    }
    // uint256[] public anArray;
    People[] public people;

    mapping(string => uint256) public nameToFavoriteNumber;

    function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        favoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber;
    }

    function retrieve() public view returns (uint256) {
        return favoriteNumber;
    }

    function addPerson(string memory _name, uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        people.push(People(_favoriteNumber, _name));
        nameToFavoriteNumber[_name] = _favoriteNumber;
    }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "ethers": "5.7.2",
    "fs-extra": "^11.1.0",
    "solc": "0.8.7-fixed"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "yarn solcjs --bin --abi --include-path node_modules/ --base-path . -o . SimpleStorage.sol"
  }
}
```

Can anyone help please? The everything compiles fine - and the `SimpleStorage.sol` contract deploys on remix without any issues...

Thanks!

Comment: I've edited the post to remove the private key you had included when initializing the Ethers Wallet. While I suspect that it was an unfunded private key intended for testing, it's better to never expose a private key online.

Answer (score 0):

```
  const binary = fs.readFileSync(
    "./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi",
    "utf8"
  );
```

Your error is due to loading the wrong file. Instead of loading the `bytecode` (binary), you are loading the `ABI`.

That's the reason of this error, you can verify by yourself at `value` it is reverting with the `ABI` values:

```
Error: invalid bytecode (argument="bytecode", value="[{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"string\",\"name\":\"_name\",\"type\":\"string\"}
```